# How do I get the sum of all solutions to a predicate (given that the set of solutions is finite)?

Tags: prolog

`modThreeModFive(X) :- X > 0, X < 1000, 0 is mod(X, 5) ; 0 is mod(X, 3).`

I'm wondering what the simplest way would be to get the sum of values of X for which the statement is true, given that the number of solutions is finite.

Is this even possible in Prolog, or am I forced to fill a list with integers [1, 1000], and then test them individually?

Comment: Instead of a list you can use forall and between in SWI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being so different from imperative languages, the easiest way is to use a [library predicate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate):

```erlang
?- [user].
|: modThreeModFive(X) :- X > 0, X < 1000, 0 is mod(X, 5) ; 0 is mod(X, 3).
|: 
% user://1 compiled 0.05 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- aggregate(sum(X),(between(1,1000,X),modThreeModFive(X)),Sum).
Sum = 266333.
```

Not every Prolog has such library, then the alternative would be to - as you already suggested - to first get the list of values, then sum them together:

```erlang
?- findall(X,(between(1,1000,X),modThreeModFive(X)),L),sumlist(L,Sum).
L = [3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 15, 18|...],
Sum = 266333.
```

If your Prolog allows for non backtrackable assignment, you could implement by yourself some of the basic functionalities found in library(aggregate).

OT: the version summing a list shows a bug in your logic: 15 is a solution in *both* branches. Instead of disjunction, you should use an if/then/else construct. Like in

```erlang
?- [user].
|: modThreeModFive(X) :- 0 is mod(X, 5) -> true ; 0 is mod(X, 3).

Warning: user://2:21:
Warning:    Redefined static procedure modThreeModFive/1
Warning:    Previously defined at user://1:8
|: 
% user://2 compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.

?- findall(X,(between(1,1000,X),modThreeModFive(X)),L),sumlist(L,Sum).
L = [3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20|...],
Sum = 234168.
```

or just a cut [!/0](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0) to commit the first outcome. It's an useful exercise to find out the right position in such simple predicate...